# get arrays which match using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

The first Array:

```
let array1 = [
   {label:'john', value:1},
   {label:'susan', value:2},
   {label:'ann', value:3}
 ]
```

The second Array:

```
let array2 = [
 {id:1, name:'john', age:12},
 {id:3, name:'ann', age:24}
]
```

What am looking forward is to get all the array1 objects which value matches with id in array2

So basically the solution should have:

```
{label:'john', value:1}
{label:'ann', value:3}
```

So I have tried:

```
let matches  = [];
 array1.forEach((item1)=>{
   array2.forEach((item2)=>{
    if(item2.id === item1.value){
      matches.push() //stuck here 

   }
  })

})
```

Am stuck on how to push the items to a new array. Also looking at my code it looks abit messy. 
How do i refactor the code to work .

Comment: Do you want to match the value with the id _only_? Meaning, would `{id:1, name:'hubert', age:99}` in the second array still be considered a “match” for `{label:'john', value:1}` from the first?

Answer (score 4):

You could filter `array2` and take only the objects where `value` matches `id` in `array2`.

Methods:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering an array, retuns a new array with itmes where the callback returns a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value,
- [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which searches for an item, which meet the condition.
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), like `{ value }` for getting only the property with that name.

```js
var array1 = [{ label: 'john', value: 1 }, { label: 'susan', value: 2 }, { label: 'ann', value: 3 }],
    array2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'john', age: 12 }, { id: 3, name: 'ann', age: 24 }],
    result = array1.filter(({ value }) =>
        array2.find(({ id }) => 
            value === id
        )
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i think the readability is not good.Does that mean i am still not familiar with ES6? or the readability is truly not good

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
let array1 = [
   {label:'john', value:1},
   {label:'susan', value:2},
   {label:'ann', value:3}
 ]

let array2 = [
 {id:1, name:'john', age:12},
 {id:3, name:'ann', age:24}
]
var matches = [];
array1.forEach(function(item1){
  array2.forEach(function(item2){
    if(item1.value == item2.id)
      matches.push(item1)
  });
});
console.log(matches);
```